# Streamline/resize array size in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, resize

I have the following code:

```
Function SplitMe(sourceArray As Variant) As Variant
Dim source As Variant, tempArr As Variant
source = sourceArray

If Not IsArray(source) Then _
    Exit Function

Dim r As Integer
Dim parts() As String
Dim splitted As Variant
ReDim splitted(LBound(source) To UBound(source))

For r = LBound(source) To UBound(source)
    parts = VBA.Split(source(r, 1), "\")
    splitted(r) = parts
Next r
```

It works fine until here:

```
splitted = Application.Transpose(splitted)
SplitMe = splitted

For r = LBound(splitted) To UBound(splitted)
    Debug.Print uniqueValues(splitted, r)
Next r
End Function
```

At this Point I want to transpose the Array. It works fine if the Arrays within the splited Array are the same size. The Problem occurs when I have a query like this:

[image: Array of Array before transposing]

The transposing is necessary for the  `uniqueValues(splitted, r)` function.

I now want to write a function that goes ahead and adds length to the queries that are not the maximal size.
  In this case `splitted(1)` would give the length `0 to 9` and then the other 5 nodes would need to be increased to be `0 to 9`.

Anyone with a function at hand that does that?

Comment: Why not try writing it? You'd need to loop through `splitted` twice: on the first pass find the maximum size of each sub-array and on the second pass use `Redim Preserve` to resize as required.

Comment: Yeah, I am currently in the process of writing it myself. I didn't find a solution online and thought maybe someone had one. I will answer the question with a working code as soon as I am done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function resizes an Array of an Array to the same dimensions:

```
Function oneDimensionArray(tmpArr As Variant, maxDim As Long) As Variant
Dim r As Long, redimArray As Variant
For r = LBound(tmpArr) To UBound(tmpArr)
    redimArray = tmpArr(r)
    If maxDim > UBound(redimArray) Then ReDim Preserve redimArray(LBound(redimArray) To maxDim)
    tmpArr(r) = redimArray
Next r

oneDimensionArray = tmpArr
End Function
```